# coinbase php rest invalid signature

Tags: php, signature, coinbase-api

I keep getting invalid signature trying to get user details. I've read a bunch of different posts and just can't seem to figure what i'm doing wrong.

initial request to get server time. this part works and returns a unix timestamp:

```
$timestamp  = time();
$request = 'v2/time';
$message = $timestamp.'GET'.$request;
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $message,$this->api_secret);
 $api = new RestClient([
        'base_url' => "https://api.coinbase.com",
        'format' => "json",
        'headers' => [
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY' => $this->api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' => $sig,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' => $timestamp
            //'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.OAUTH_BEARER
        ],
    ]);

            $timestamp = json_decode(($api->get($request))->response)->data->epoch;
```

second request to get user info, this fails

```
    $timestamp (from previous request)
    $request = 'v2/user';
    $message = $timestamp.'GET'.$request;
    $sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $message,$this->api_secret);
    $api = new RestClient([
        'base_url' => "https://api.coinbase.com",
        'format' => "json",
        'headers' => [
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY' => $this->api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN' => $sig,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP' => $timestamp
            //'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.OAUTH_BEARER
        ],
    ]);

    $result = $api->get($request);
```

response -> string (72) "{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}"

Comment: Did you make sure that "Your timestamp must be within 30 seconds of the api service time or your request will be considered expired and rejected. We recommend using the time endpoint to query for the API server time if you believe there many be time skew between your server and the API servers." per https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#api-key?

Comment: apologies i'll update the question with that code. I did try pulling their timestamp first, and still get the same error.